# angular2 getters breaking MDL components

Tags: angular, getter-setter, material-design-lite

So, first of all I am using Material Design Lite in case that has anything to do with my weird problem.

I have a page that contains list component

```
<my-list [list]="list"></my-list>
```

now that list internally contains another component (which is MDL switch: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section/switch)

```
<my-toggle [toggle]="toggle"></my-toggle>
```

and this is the data that the page feeds to the list

```
list: MyList = {
    items: [{
        id: 'example-id',
        primaryContent: {
            title: 'Example Title',
        },
        secondaryContent: {
            toggle: {
                id: 'example-toggle-id',
                checked: this.dynamicVarExample,
                type: 'switch'
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

But when I change it to getter (so the data gets refreshed and my-list shows up-to-date dynamicVarExample), my switch stops working.

```
get list(): MyList{
    return {
        items: [{
            id: 'example-id',
            primaryContent: {
                title: 'Example Title',
            },
            secondaryContent: {
                toggle: {
                    id: 'example-toggle-id',
                    checked: this.dynamicVarExample,
                    type: 'switch'
                }
            }

        }]
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Seems like getters do something with events.

Comment: What is the `enter code here` doing in the first example?

Comment: @birwin It is a stackoverflow question editor functionality but I am not sure why it is there - anyway I removed the line now